# Components with uppercase function names are rendered multiple times in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been developing with Hooks for a long time, But I met a situation where I was confused.

Let me briefly describe this strange problem with a particular case.

I created a very simple functional component called `Test`:

```js
// test.js
export default function Test () {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Test')
  }, [])

  return (
    <h2>
      Test Component
    </h2>
  )
}
```

It will print something at the first render

And the component will be referenced in `App`

```js
// App.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Test from './test';

export default function App() {
  const [number, updateNumber] = useState(0);

  const renderComponent = () => {
    return (
      <Test />
    )
  }

  const RenderComponent = () => {
    return (
      <Test />
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    updateNumber(1)
    updateNumber(2)
  }, [])

  console.log('every-render')

  return (
    <div className="App">

      {renderComponent()}

      {/* <RenderComponent /> */}

      <h1>Rerender times: {number}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So something strange happened

When I use this way, the `Test` component will be printed once

```js
// Case 1
const renderComponent = () => {
    return (
      <Test />
    )
}

// ...

renderComponent()
```

[Something that it prints in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz7Nr.png)

But when I use this way, the `Test` component will be printed twice

```js
// Case 2
const RenderComponent = () => {
    return (
      <Test />
    )
}

// ...

<RenderComponent />
```

[Something that it prints in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdO5M.png)

**Of course, I wrote a demo for you to debug**: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-for-hooks-8gkml?file=/src/App.js

I am confused why in case 2 the `Test` component will be remounted each time the Hooks are rerendered.

Answer (score 0):

Every render cycle the `RenderComponent` component is recreated, so it is mounted every render, and thus, mounts its children. Consider the following code where you render `<Test />` directly, it's output is identical to `{renderComponent()}`.

```
export default function App() {
  const [number, updateNumber] = useState(0);

  const renderComponent = () => {
    return <Test />;
  };

  const RenderComponent = () => {
    return <Test />;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updateNumber(1);
    updateNumber(2);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("every-render");
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* {renderComponent()} */}
      {/* <RenderComponent /> */}
      <Test /> // <-- "Mounted Test", "every-render", "every-render"

      <h1>Rerender times: {number}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The function `renderComponent` is executed and the return value ***is*** `<Test />`, thus equivalent to just rendering `<Test />` directly, whereas `RenderComponent` is a new component each cycle.

[image: Edit weird rendering issue (maybe, maybe not)]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes, the use of RenderComponent was specifically used in this case.

But I'm confused in
Why would use *<RenderComponent />*，*Test* will render multiple times
But if use *renderComponent()*, *Test* would't render more times

Comment: But every render we recreate `renderComponent`, why it's mount once?

Comment: @NikitaMadeev True, the function is redefined each render cycle, but the return value `<Test />` placed in the reactDOM is the same.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, i tried to enhance your answer below :)

Comment: @NikitaMadeev Oh holy screen refresh Batman, hadn't seen that, but yes, good details. I just came back to edit my answer after thinking about it for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

[When diffing two trees, React first compares the two root elements. The behavior is different depending on the types of the root elements.](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#the-diffing-algorithm)

Consider 3 cases:

```
{renderComponent()}
<RenderComponent />
<Test />
```

1) `{renderComponent()}`

Every render just return `Test` type, algorithm compares and sees that the type has not changed.
Result: mount `Test` component 1 time.

2) `<RenderComponent />`

Every render return *new* component type `RenderComponent`, algorithm compares and sees `RenderComponent1 type` != `RenderComponent2 type`, and:

> Whenever the root elements have different types, React will tear down the old tree and build the new tree from scratch.

Result: mount child `Test` component 2 times.

Add console to mount `RenderComponent`:

```
const RenderComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => console.log('RenderComponent mount'), []);
    return <Test />;
};
```

RenderComponent too mount 2 times.

3) `<Test />`

Similarly 1 case.
Result: mount `Test` component 1 time.

Comment: For #2, Adding `key` still renders twice and extracting `RenderComponent` outside the app only render once.

Comment: Yes, if we extracting `RenderComponent` outside the app, we will have one type every render

Comment: So you mentioned that the Reconciler algorithm will tear down the old tree coz RC1 !== RC2. So how come adding a `key` doesn't work also?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, then `key` can help only with the same types, in our case type RC1 !== RC2

Comment: I like your instructions, but we seem to be in a situation where we are trying to justify the cause with results.     
I want to know and see the explanation of the principle more

Comment: @nanyang24 I think this is already beyond the scope of your question, you should refer to the official documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html